# How to write a good GMock matcher for two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, matcher, googlemock

I needed a limited set of algebra operations on two dimensional matrices for my C++ code. I decided to implement this using `std::array` like so:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
using array_2d = std::array<std::array<T, M>, N>;
```

How should I properly write a GMock matcher for this type, to compare two such matrices of doubles?
I came up with the not so smart:

```
MATCHER_P(Arrays2dDoubleEq, expected, "") {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].size(); j++) {
            EXPECT_THAT(arg[i][j], DoubleEq(expected[i][j]));
        }
    }
    return true;
}

MATCHER_P2(Arrays2dDoubleNear, expected, max_abs_err, "") {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].size(); j++) {
            EXPECT_THAT(arg[i][j], DoubleNear(expected[i][j], max_abs_err));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which I use like: `EXPECT_THAT(result, Arrays2dDoubleEq(expected));`

This not only looks very hard coded, but also doesn't give nice feedback. When matrices mismatch the output of failed assertions is a pile of not equal doubles. The failed test output is hardly readable and lacks info about indexes of matrices.

I feel that it can be done (and should be done) in much better way. I have already looked at some documentation and GMock cookbook. Although there are some matchers for containers I can't make any use of them to compare two nested arrays at once.

Can anyone indicate which GMock functionalities I should use to make this matcher better? Or perhaps someone can point a part of documentation that I should read more carefully to understand what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you might consider is to explicitly return `false` or `true` form your matcher instead calling assertions. Then you can use `result_listener` to provide additional information about what exactly went wrong during match. You should also check the arrays dimensions before performing the check to avoid undefined bahavior

```
using testing::DoubleEq;
using testing::Value;
using testing::Not;

MATCHER_P(Arrays2dDoubleEq, expected, "") {
  if (arg.size() != expected.size())
  {
    *result_listener << "arg.size() != expected.size() ";
    *result_listener << arg.size() << " vs " << expected.size();
    return false;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++) {
    if (arg[i].size() != expected[i].size())
    {
      *result_listener << "arg[i].size() != expected[i].size() i = " << i << "; ";
      *result_listener << arg[i].size() << " vs " << expected[i].size();
      return false;
    }
    for (size_t j = 0; j < arg[i].size(); j++) {
      if (!Value(arg[i][j], DoubleEq(expected[i][j])))
      {
        *result_listener << "element(" << i << ", " << j << ") mismatch ";
        *result_listener << arg[i][j] << " vs " << expected[i][j];
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

TEST(xxx, yyy)
{
  array_2d<double, 2, 3> arr1 = {std::array<double, 3>({1, 2, 3}), std::array<double, 3>({4, 5, 6})};
  array_2d<double, 2, 3> arr2 = arr1;
  array_2d<double, 2, 3> arr3 = arr1;
  arr3[0][0] = 69.69;
  array_2d<double, 5, 6> arr4;
  ASSERT_THAT(arr1, Arrays2dDoubleEq(arr2));
  ASSERT_THAT(arr2, Not(Arrays2dDoubleEq(arr3)));
  ASSERT_THAT(arr2, Not(Arrays2dDoubleEq(arr4)));
}
```

Unfortunately, I didn't figure out yet how to tell gmock not to print the contents of `std::array` in `Value of` and `Expected` feedback fields. in the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md) they mention `void PrintTo` function, but it did not work for me.

=== EDIT ===

If it is OK for you to create a 2D array class instead of typedef, then it is easy to suppress gmock messy output by providing `operator<<` overload:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
struct Array2D
{
  std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> data;
};

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array2D<T, N, M>&)
{
  os << "Array2D<" << typeid(T).name() << "," << N << "," << M << ">";
  return os;
}
```

Then you need to modify the matcher a bit to use `data` class field instead of `operator[]` and `size()` directly. Or you can overload them for your class.

If the comment of @JanHackenberg is what you desire, inside your matcher just set flag `result = false` instead of `return` (I wouldn't do that though, because for big arrays it will not be readable).

Comment: You immediately return after the first `*result_listener << "element(" << i << ", " << j << ") mismatch ";` with false, but there might be more mismatches which you skip by your return. Kudos for checking the sizes as well-

Comment: @JanHackenberg yes, I return immediately, because if one element doesn't match, it means that arrays are not the same and there is no point checking further.

Comment: The point is that the topic creator has an interest in the failing indices.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `result_listener` thing. I decided to stick with using the `typedef` approach. Also appreciate that you included dimensions checking. The results seem satisfactory to me so this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get information about indices and seem to not want to get actual values. How about:

```
MATCHER_P(Arrays2dDoubleEq, expected, "") {
    bool allMatched = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arg[i].size(); j++) {
            if(arg[i][j] != expected[i][j]) {
                 std::cout << "Failing at indices:" << i << ";" << j << std::endl;
                 allMatched = false;
            }
        }
    }
    EXPECT_THAT(allMatched, true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `*result_listener` object instead of  `std::cout`. This way the output will be also visible in any other place where Googletest might output (like XML file used by IDE to present results in graphical form)